# How to delete a pull request?

Tags: git, github

I am getting a deployment error and I want to delete an unmerged pull request.  I have to make changes to the pulled code and create a new PR.

Comment: So what's stopping you?

Comment: Aside from that, why do you need to make a new PR? Just update the one you have.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+update+pull+request

Answer (score 3):

You could just update the PR by committing to the branch you made the PR from. If this doesn't work for some reason and you truly need to make a New PR then navigate to the Pull Request on GitHub and close it. If you need to truly "Delete" if you have to contact GitHub Support.

[image]

Comment: "If you need to truly "Delete" if you have to contact GitHub Support" -- and they will probably laugh at you.

Comment: They will delete it if it contains sensitive data. Which is likely the cause of wanting to delete the PR here.

Comment: The cause is "I am getting a deployment error". I don't think that's about sensitive data. I think it's just a broken PR, and someone who doesn't understand how PRs work.

Comment: Ah... Right. Well, without more info this is his best option.